# Adobe Acrobat: create a sequential number field with format "000001"

Tags: javascript, adobe-acrobat

From [this page](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1337419), I've inserted an automatically incremental "serial" field in a PDF, by using JavaScript:

```
var f = this.getField("Serial");
f.value = Number(f.value)+1;
f.defaultValue = f.value;
```

This works as expected, but we'd like the format of the serial to be `000001` instead of `1`.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You would use the util.printf() method to format your number.

If it is only for visual purpose, you would add the following to the Format event of your field:

```
event.value = util.printf("%06d", event.value) ;
```

and that should do it. You can, of course, use this snippet in your calculation code as well.